# Absolute positioning relative to list items

Tags: css

I want to give a list item a background-color, border etc. I have the following CSS and HTML. I will also use that div to add more absolute positioned elements relative to the li > div.

```
ul {
    list-style-image: url('../img/nr_cross.png');
}

li {
    position: relative;
    height: 35px;
}

div {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    left:-40px;
    background-color: #dfdfc9;
}

<ul>
<li><p>This</p></li>
<li><p>That</p></li>
<li><p>Other</p></li>
<ul>
```

The problem is, i cant set the z-index for the list item. If i set the absolute position for the list item, it defeats the purpose of using the list items for layout. I'm thinking this is impossible, or maybe there is a better way to do what I want.

**Update:**

[image: Mock]

**Update 2:**

Answer below does not work in firefox 10, ie8, ie7. Also fixed question above.

Comment: I missed the part where you asked a question.

Comment: Can you like make a mockup of how you want it to look? Or maybe I'm just being slow and someone else will know what you're talking about

Comment: Yeah I'm **GCC** I don't get what you're tryin' to do

Comment: I don't get why you need all those extra `<div>`-s  and `<p>`-s? Why don't you just style your `<li>` the way you want it to look?

Comment: I want to give the list item a background color, underneath the list-style-image.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that mockup clears things up. I think. Does this work for you?

```
ul {
    list-style-image: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/splashyIcons/breadcrumb_separator_arrow_full.png);
    background-color: #dfdfc9;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

p {
    position: relative;
    left: 2em;   
}

li {
    border-bottom: 2px dotted black;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dbT2n/1/

Comment: Ive added a mockup. I want to have background colour behind list-item-image, and a border on the bottom. It doesnt have to be a div, though the div will be in there because I will have a number of elements inside each list item, expander, custom tool tips, relative to the li > div.

Comment: @madphp Yeah it does, it's the little arrow =/

Comment: It doesnt work in firefox, ie8, ie7. Works in chrome, ie9 and safari.

Comment: @madphp fun. Well, let me know if you figure it out.

Comment: Did you get those points fixing peoples grammar and general cynicism, because it cant have been for answering css questions.